# Ionic looks different in simulator and ionic view

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an app using Ionic for the first time and everything is going great, the only problem right now is that if I run my app in the simulator and the browser the app looks as I designed but when I run `ionic upload` and try to test it on my iPhone 6 using the Ionic View app, I just get a white screen :(

Is there a reason why ionic view and the simulator or browser could be different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it! The problem was in my states...I had the templateUrl as '../views/games/games-list.html' and all I had to remove was the '../' and it fixed it.